# Python interpreter as in-game console

Tags: c++, python, console

Say I have a game which has lots objects (NPCs, monsters, etc.), I want a console so I can change the variables of the objects (like changing HP for example), how could I embed python into my program, so that I can change these variables and classes with a few keystrokes in the console? An example of a command would be: `/monster 1 1 HP 100` (`monster` is the object name, `1 1` is the coordinates, and `HP 100` is the variable to change, and to what amount)

Comment: Does this link answer your question? https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratingPythonWithOtherLanguages#C.2FC.2B-.2B-

Comment: @Philipp It's helpful, but doesn't tell me how to access classes using Python, it just says how I could embed python (which I have already done, using `#include <Python.h>` with python in the project directory

Comment: @bboy3577 it isn't very easy, but that link does show you quite a few ways of doing it. If you're using C/C++ [boost python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/index.html) is probably the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: @bboy3577 in particular, [this chapter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html) shows how to do it.